# Payment as a Donation

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a registration form for an event where people help local non-profits.  I would like to add a spot at the bottom of the form where participants can donate to the event to help cover the costs of the non-profits.

How would you recommend I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

The best way to add a field to your form, that end users can use to add a value to the form that they would like to pay would be the Currency field.

[image]

[image]

Once added you can then select to collect payment for the field. This will let your end user not only select the amount they would like to add but then pay via the payment gateway added to your form; Stripe, PayPal or Square.

[image]